# Python error in plots hierarchy : TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm developing a class hierarchy for product my style plot useful for my purpose,

I received the error report in the title  `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` when I try to instantiate the plot from a subclass , 
I have simplify this class in order to isolate the error , but these classes can be used and tested, in particular I receive this error only when I try to call from the subclass , in I call the top-level one I didn't get and the plot is produced 
now let me reported the several classes :

the hierarchy start with an abstract class :

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from cycler import cycler

class BasePlot(metaclass=ABCMeta):

   def __init__(self, title : str = ' ' , filename : str = ' '):
      self.title = title
      self.filename = filename   

   def schemes(self, style:str = 'nb'):
         color = {} 
         color['nb']   = ['#8DA0CB', '#E58AC3', '#A6D853', '#FFD930', '#B2B2B2', '#5FC3A4', '#FC8D62', '#66C2A5']
         return color[style]

   def linestyles(self, style : str = 'ls1'):  
         linestyles = {}
         linestyles['paper'] = [(0, ()), (0, (3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), (0, (5, 5)),(0, (5, 1)),(0, (3, 5, 1, 5)),(0, (3, 5, 1, 5, 1, 5)),(0, (1, 1)),(0, (5, 10)) ]
         return linestyles[style]                                                                                                   

   @abstractmethod
   def style(self,*args,**kwargs):
      pass
```

from this base class inherited a class in which almost every thing that I need is defined this is named the default class that produce the default plot !

```
 class DefaultPlot(BasePlot) :

    def __init__(self, figsize,*args,**kwargs):
        self.var = [*args]
        self.params = kwargs
    def style(self,*args):
        self.variable = [*args]
    def cycle(self,n : str):
            if n == '0':
                  return plt.cycler("color", self.parameters['scheme'])      #colors)         
            elif n=='1':
                  return plt.cycler("color", self.parameters['scheme']) + plt.cycler("linestyles", self.parameters['linestyles'])
    def setparams(self, kwargs):
             self.parameters = kwargs
             if 'scheme' in self.parameters.keys():
                 v = self.parameters['scheme']  
                 self.parameters['scheme'] = self.schemes(v)

             if 'font' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['font'] = 'serif'
             if 'scheme' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['scheme'] = self.schemes('nb')
             if 'cycle' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['cycle']  = self.cycle('0')
             if 'linestyles' not in self.parameters.keys():
                self.parameters['linestyles'] = self.linestyles('paper')


             myparams = {
               'axes.prop_cycle': self.parameters['cycle'],     
               'grid.color' : 'gray',
               'font.family': self.parameters['font'] ,
               'font.style' : 'italic'
             }

             plt.rcParams.update(myparams)

    def __call__ (self,nrows,ncols,*args,**kwargs):

       self.style(*args)
       self.setparams(kwargs)

       if nrows == ncols ==1:
            self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(nrows,ncols,figsize=(9.5,4.5))
       else:
            self.fig, self.axs = plt.subplots(nrows,ncols,figsize=(12,6))
       for i in range(nrows):
          for j in range(ncols):
             if nrows == ncols == 1:
                 self.axs.set_title('', color='#555555')
                 legend = leg = self.axs.legend()

             else:
                 self.axs[i,j].set_title('', color='#555555')
                 legend = leg = self.axs[i,j].legend()
             legend.get_frame().set_linewidth(1.2)
             plt.setp(legend.get_texts(), color='#555555')

             if nrows == ncols ==1 :
                plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.125 , bottom=0.125, right=0.95, top=0.87, wspace=0, hspace=0)
             else:   
                plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.06 , bottom=0.1, right=0.95, top=0.95, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.4)
       return self.fig,self.axs
```

finally I inherit  the last level class the pourpose of this class (even though here dos't look ) is to replace the parameters defined in the above default class in order to create several class like this to produce a style plot (basically in this one I replace the color .. the font the ticks and so on)

```
class Standard(DefaultPlot):

def __init__(self , figsize , *args , **kwargs):
    self.args = [*args]
    self.params = kwargs
    super().__init__(figsize,*self.args, **self.params )

def setparams(self, kwargs):

         self.parameters = kwargs
         if 'scheme' in self.parameters.keys():
              v = self.parameters['scheme']  
              self.parameters['scheme'] = self.schemes(v)
         if 'linestyles' not in self.parameters.keys():
            self.parameters['linestyles'] = self.linestyles('paper')
         if 'scheme' not in self.parameters.keys():
            self.parameters['scheme'] = self.schemes('nb')
         if 'cycle' not in self.parameters.keys():
            self.parameters['cycle']  = self.cycle('0')

         super().setparams(self.parameters)
```

and this class is called from the main script :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import defaultplot 
import qualityplot

def main():

    x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)
    y = np.sin(x)

    fig,axs = qualityplot.Standard(figsize=(9.5,4.5))(1,1,**{'scheme':'nb'})
    #fig,axs = defaultplot.DefaultPlot(figsize=(9.5,4.5))(1,1,**{'scheme':'nb'})

    axs.plot(x,y)
    plt.show()
```

Now if you try to run and call qualityplot you recieve the error : `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` but if you call the top level defaultpolot.DefaultPlot (the last commented line) the things goin fine ! I don't know what i'm wrong ! 
how can I fix the things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that you cannot use a list as a dictionary key. I.e. the following is **not possible** in python

```
a = {[1,2,3] : "A"}
```

In your code this problem occurs because you change the type of `self.parameters['scheme']`. It may first be  string, and then gets turned to a list in the following piece of code.

```
     self.parameters = kwargs
     if 'scheme' in self.parameters.keys():
          v = self.parameters['scheme']  
          self.parameters['scheme'] = self.schemes(v)
```

Now this piece is called a second time in the super method, with `self.parameters['scheme']` already being a list. In this case `self.schemes(list)` is not useful and will result in the error.

Comment: so could you explain to me why with the defaultplot class it works and not for qualityplot .. I think I don't well get your answer sorry ! is fixable ?

Comment: I said, "this piece is called a second time". That only happens in the subclass. If you directly use `DefaultPlot` it is only called once and the argument to schemes stays a string. As a fix, I would propose not to alter the same object, but use a different one instead.

Comment: different one that always inherit from defaultplots ?

Comment: May you explain to me how would you organize the code? just some hints

Comment: The code seems pretty redundant to me, so I would simply use a single class and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

In `schemes` function, you set color['nb'] to a list.

In `Standard.setparams` function, you put this list into `self.parameters['scheme']` then you call `DefaultPlot.setparams`

In `DefaultPlot.setparams` you call `BasePlot.schemes(v)` with v equal to this list

In `BasePlot.schemes` you call `return color[style]` with style equal to this list, which cannot work (style should be a string)